# Is there some function to clear all viewer iterms in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there some function to clear all viewer iterms in RStudio? so I donot need to clear manually.

Answer (score 0):

Not an R function but a Mozilla hotkey:
CTRL + Shift + W

It will prompt you to save scripts, though.